# Very basic formatting Issue

Tags: python, formatting

If I have a list such as the following:

```
[(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]
```

How could I make this look like this:

```
'10-20,50-60,100-110'
```

if the number of pairs in my list is variable?

I am sorry for such an easy question. But every thing I have tried such as replacing the ',' with a '-' has failed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> x = [(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]
>>> ','.join('-'.join(map(str, t)) for t in x)
'10-20,50-60,100-110'
```

Comment: Could I do this 'string'+'|'+(','.join('-'.join(map(str, t)) for t in x)) and get string|10-20,50-60,100-110??

Comment: @PatrickCampbell, Yes, you could also do `'string|%s' % ','.join('-'.join(map(str, t)) for t in x)` to avoid string concatentation.

Comment: Could you help me with a similar question here please?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359993/going-to-a-certain-position-in-a-string

Answer (score 2):

Another (somewhat more readable) way to do this formatting is to use either

A) % style string formatting:

```
data = [(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]

fmt = "%d-%d, %d-%d, %d-%d" % (data[0][0], data[0][1], data[1][0], data[1][1],...)
```

or, with a list comprehension:

```
fmt = ",".join("%d-%d" % i for i in data)
```

B) The python `string.format` method:

```
fmt = ",".join("{0}-{1}".format(*i) for i in data)
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, could you look here to see what I was talking about before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359993/going-to-a-certain-position-in-a-string

Comment: ^^I cannot get this to work, I think you can make a simple fix

Comment: @PatrickCampbell: It works perfectly fine for me. What, specifically, can you not get to work?

Comment: It gives me the error saying 'starts' is not defined and ends the program

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
data = [(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]
for x in data:
    print x[0], "-", x[1]
```

Comment: Yes, something very close. However, I want to add that to a string I already have. So what would I do if I had string+?????

Comment: I'm not sure how your program is structured but instead of print you could append the result to your existing string? or if you merge later in your program you can make a list with the data being printed and then append it later on

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the values of the list while iterating over it within a comprehension:

```
>>> x = [(10, 20), (50, 60), (100, 110)]
>>> ','.join('%d-%d' % (y,z) for (y,z) in x)
'10-20,50-60,100-110'
```